# How to make it possible to replace a variable between 2 constants from an HTML document with JavaScript on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, replace, constants

I have this case where on an html page I have an input and I have to be able to replace the value between two constants with the value from the input. How would I approach this with JavaScipt? I thought about using regular expression but not sure how to define the two constants. Maybe something like

```
var1 = textpart1;
var2 = textpart2;
```

Then maybe.

```
$("#buttonelementID").click(function() {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/varX/g,"VALUE_FROM_INPUT"));
    });
});
```

But this would be a regular replace of something with something else. Once the old value of the variable is changed, script won't be able to change it again because script won't find the new value of the variable because it is already changed to something else. How do I define to the script what is **varX** and the **value from input**? I am a bit lost with this slice then splice thing. Maybe this is how it should actually work. Like define array of 3 items where the 2nd item is the one to be changed, but then again I am not sure how to define this. The thing is that the variable will be between 2 parts of text that would never change, so I guess I am on the right path on this. The text is in a textbox, if that matters but with this approach, I guess not. Array insert could work but not sure if it is possible to insert variable in a position and how to define that the array items are from that html element. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by:

jQuery

```
$("#apply").click(function() {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(?<=\*).*?(?=\))/g,$("#cap").val()));
    });
});
```

Here goes the HTML:

```
<div id="capping" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <label class="trackings">Hours:</label> <input type="number" min="1" class="select-selected" id="cap" name="cap" size="1" maxlength="3"> 
        </li>
    </ul>
        <button id="apply" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Apply
        </button>
</div>
```

The string I was looking for was between a * and a ), hence the regex and the input I wanted to receive the value from has element id named input. Now I have another problem. This works just once, as I expected, but also the value disappears from the input field once the apply button with element id apply is clicked. Any ideas how I could make it work on each click for whatever the current value is in the input without making the value disappear from the input field? Question in the answer... Good one.